# How to create trigger that counts sum of column and inserts it into another one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to put sum of one column into column from another table. Everything for each ID. At start my columns are NULL, so I want to update them with this value.

Untill now I've tried to count SUM and it works, of course, but when I'm trying to write more code, it fails everytime. More. It's not that I can't code that if I want to. I just can't find logic that would make me feel like "Oh, I should go that way". This is my first trigger and it's really hard for me. Sadly all answers on StackOverflow looks much harder than my own.

UPDATE: Just found out there are built in fuctions. Is there any that makes things like that possible?

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS daily;

CREATE TABLE daily (
    idd SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    p_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    dailyDate DATE NOT NULL,
    dailyKcal INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    burnedKcal INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(p_id) REFERENCES proteges(idp)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exercises;

CREATE TABLE exercises (
    d_did INTEGER NOT NULL,
    exerciseName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    startAt TIME NOT NULL,
    endAt TIME NOT NULL,
    kcalPerHour INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (d_did) REFERENCES daily(idd)
);

--- FAIL ---
CREATE TRIGGER update_daily_exercises 
    AFTER INSERT ON exercises
    UPDATE daily 
    SET burnedkcal = (SELECT sum(kcalperhour) FROM exercises GROUP BY d_did)
    WHERE idd = d_did
```

What do I expect?
Let's say there is something like that:

```
d_did | ... | kcalperhour
1     | ... | 492
2     | ... | 321
1     | ... | 346
```

```
idd | ... | burnedkcal
1   | ... | NULL
2   | ... | NULL
```

And after POST I want it to be like:

```
idd | ... | burnedkcal
1   | ... | 838
2   | ... | 321
```

Comment: The trigger calls a function, and this function does the work. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-EXAMPLES

Comment: Ok, and I need to create them or there are built in? On this site u just shared, there are some functions, but nothing more. I dont know how they look. Are they built in?

Comment: no, you create them

Comment: Ok, so my trigger looks fine for my example?
```CREATE TRIGGER update_daily_exercises 
    AFTER INSERT ON exercises
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE FUNCTION sum_exercises(); ``` Now I have to create function? Or even my trigger is bad?

Comment: yes, just as in the doc examples.

Comment: And now function. Seems fine? `CREATE FUNCTION sum_exercises(x INTEGER) DECLARE total INTEGER; BEGIN SELECT sum(kcalPerHour) FROM exercises WHERE d_did = $1 INTO total; UPDATE daily SET burnedKcal = total; END;` Sorry for taking your time, but it's last thing I need to complete my project and I really wanted to use triggers. They look so nice. Ofc added argument into my trigger `CREATE TRIGGER update_daily_exercises AFTER INSERT ON exercises FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION sum_exercises(idd);`

Comment: UPDATE, did something like that and function passed. `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_exercises(x INTEGER) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    total INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT sum(kcalPerHour) FROM exercises JOIN daily ON idd = d_did WHERE d_did = x INTO total;
    UPDATE daily SET burnedKcal = total WHERE idd = x;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;` and now when i try to use trigger like before, it says "Function doesnt exist"...

Comment: Did that function return what you were expecting? then, it's right. Otherwise you must change it.

Comment: Cant check it because of "function does not exist" info after trigger input.

Comment: `\df public.*;
                                List of functions
 Schema |     Name     | Type of return | Type of arguments | Type  
---------+---------------+-------------------+------------------------+------
 public  | sum_exercises | void              | x integer              | func
`
But this still says function does not exist after:
`CREATE TRIGGER update_daily_exercises 
    AFTER INSERT ON exercises
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.sum_exercises(d_did);` Fml

Comment: Ok, tried `SELECT sum_exercises(1);` and it works. Sadly can't use trigger, which is most important.

Answer (score 0):

Materializing values that can be calculated from other values is dangerous, it can quickly lead to inconsistencies. You should rather drop the column storing the sum. If you need it, query it from the existing values. For convenience you can create a view.

```
ALTER TABLE daily
            DROP burnedkcal;

CREATE VIEW daily_with_burnedcal
AS
SELECT d.idd,
       d.p_id,
       d.dailydate,
       d.dailykcal,
       coalesce(sum(e.kcalperhour), 0) burnedkcal
       FROM daily d
            LEFT JOIN exercises e
                      ON e.d_did = d.idd
       GROUP BY d.idd,
                d.p_id,
                d.dailydate,
                d.dailykcal;
```

Comment: Sadly my professor rly wanted trigger and now I'm there. With function that exist, but can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has same problem. I'm not even sure if it's answer on my question, but I know that that's what I have done.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sum_exercises() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$update_daily_exercises$
DECLARE
    total INTEGER;
    r daily%rowtype;
BEGIN
    ---SELECT sum(kcalPerHour) FROM exercises JOIN daily ON idd = d_did WHERE d_did = x INTO total;---
    FOR r IN 
        SELECT * FROM daily ORDER BY idd DESC
    LOOP
    SELECT sum(kcalPerHour) FROM exercises JOIN daily ON idd = d_did WHERE d_did = r.idd INTO total;
    UPDATE daily SET burnedKcal = total WHERE idd = r.idd;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$update_daily_exercises$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER update_daily_exercises 
    AFTER INSERT ON exercises
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE sum_exercises();
```